# Nikto nocache option

Tags: penetration-test, vulnerability-scanners, web-scanners, nikto

I found an option

`-nocache : Disable response cache`

in here

https://cirt.net/nikto2-docs/options.html

But when I tried it, I always get this error

[image]

> Unknown option: nocache

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears the cache functionality was removed, I guess the documentation for the option wasn't removed. See the following entry in the change log which states:

> Completely remove caching functionality as it was near worthless and added a lot of overhead

https://github.com/sullo/nikto/blob/40867b08f5a9c5c8897da92c1d23ff3d1a446b4c/program/docs/CHANGES.txt#L49

Why did you want to use this option? What is the problem you're actually trying to solve?